# .Net Core 2.0 Internal Server Error with Redis Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis

I'm trying  to add Redis Cache support to my .Net Core 2.0 application and having issues after publishing to Azure App Services.

I've specified the connection string to my Azure Redis Cache in the appsetting.json, added the required bits to Startup.cs and tested storing and retrieving data locally successfully.

Once the application is published, it fails to start and only reports that there was a problem starting the application.

The line in the Startup.cs which seems to be causing the issue is:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(o => { o.Configuration = redisConnection; });
```

The string "redisConnection" is populated just above using:

```
string redisConnection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
```

I'm not sure why this would fail only when published.
How can I debug the cause of the failure?

EDIT: 
I've managed to get as far as this error, referring to the version of Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis being used.

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Bootstrap_CoreApp.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

I'm not sure why this is a problem because the referenced NuGet package in the project is set to use version 2.0.1

Comment: You're going to have to give far more information than this I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you verified that `Configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis")` is returning what you expect?

Comment: What information do you need? The app works perfectly in Visual Studio, but only gives me "An error occurred while starting the application." I don't know where to get any further information as I'm relatively new to App services.

Comment: @AlG - Yes, the confirguration string is correct and fully formed.

Comment: Given your update, it looks like the DLL didn't get deployed (or the wrong version did). Have you checked your package, etc.?

Comment: @AIG As it turns out there was nothing wrong with the project or the packages. The app service had found itself in a state and wasn't updating on deployment. In the end I deleted and recreated the app service and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I found that I added two nuget packages to the project:

1. Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis version 2.0.1
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core version 1.0.3

it worked locally, but didn't work in Azure.

then I removed Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core from the project, deployed project to Azure and site was started without any issues.